# AJAX Call in Plugin Returns More than JSON

Tags: ajax, json, plugin-gravity-forms

I have a plugin tat extendeds Gravity Forms consisting of one PHP file and a JS file.

The PHP file can be found here: http://pastebin.com/VUX5AfLP

The JS File can be found here: http://pastebin.com/CTjQEKzY

I am trying to use WP AJAX with callback to return json encoded results to populate my Gravity Form.

The issue I am having is that instead of returning the JSON encoded object to the AJAX callback, I am getting the entire injuryFilter(); function from the `<script>` to the `</script>` tags like so **in addition to the json_encoded output**:

```
<script>
        injuryFilter = function () {

var injuryClass = ".injury-list select";
var minClass = ".min-value input";
var maxClass = ".max-value input";
var results;

    jQuery(injuryClass).on("change", function () {
    var injurySelect = jQuery(this);
    injury = injurySelect.val();

            if (injury != '') {
                        var data = {
                    'action': 'get_injury_data',
                    'id': injury
                };

                    jQuery.post('http://10.200.152.19/courses/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php', data, function(response) {

                                                console.log(response);
                                                //alert("Done");



                                                //results = jQuery.parseJSON( response );
                                                //alert(response[0].min);

                    //  jQuery(minClass).val(response.min);
                    //  jQuery(maxClass).val(response.max);

                    });

                }
    });



}

</script>




[{"min":"100000","max":"150000"}]
```

Granted this is my first foray into AJAX and Plugins in Wordpress I am sure I am doing something wrong or in the wrong place.

I am just looking to get the response from AJAX so that can work with it.  If I have files or functions out of place, please be specific as to where I went wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Which explains why I couldn't use `jQuery.parseJSON()` on the result.

Comment: Where is that script tag supposed to appear? It should be added to an enqueued js file or at the minimum placed within a wp_head action call.

Comment: all that javascript is sitting in your plugin file outside of any sort of function, which means it's output on every request- front end, back end, and ajax.

Comment: Yes, you guys were right on.  I added it inside a function and  then added an action hook for `add_action( 'wp_footer', 'my_ajax_script' ); // Write our JS below here` and it works as I expected. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrapping it in a function and then adding the following did the trick:

`add_action( 'wp_footer', 'my_ajax_script' ); // Write our JS below here` Was all it took